# Convert unstructured nvarchar data into rows and columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a requirement where I have nvarchar column in the database, which I need to pull in the form of row and Column from the database.

My nvarchar is like

```
{
  "notifications": [
    {
      "apMacAddress": "20:50:7a:09:5t:30",
      "associated": false,
      "band": "IEEE_802_11_A",
      "confidenceFactor": 192,
      "deviceId": "34:f4:23:23:f4:wr",
      "entity": "Wired",
      "eventId": 2343434,
      "floorId": 3244234234234,
      "floorRefId": 234235465234,
      "geoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": -999.0,
        "longitude": -999.0,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
      },
      "ipAddress": [
        "23.423.23.234"
      ],
      "lastSeen": "2018-02-09T12:24:53.512+0000",
      "locationCoordinate": {
        "x": 423.2342,
        "y": 23.423,
        "z": 0.0,
        "unit": "FEET"
      },
      "locationMapHierarchy": "North Campus>North SIde>F4>F4 Academies ",
      "manufacturer": "Sony Corporate",
      "maxDetectedRssi": {
        "antennaIndex": 0,
        "apMacAddress": "234:23:56d:45d:5f:20",
        "band": "IEEE_802_11_B",
        "lastHeardInSeconds": 23,
        "rssi": -54,
        "slot": 2
      },
      "notificationType": "locationupdate",
      "rawLocation": {
        "RawX": 0.0,
        "RawY": 0.0,
        "Unit": null
      },
      "ssid": "aide",
      "subscriptionName": " Lab Location",
      "tagVendorData": null,
      "timestamp": 2343657436,
      "username": "abc.gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want data to be pulled up like separate columns

Here are the list of column names

```
- apMacAddress 
- associated 
- band
- confidenceFactor
- deviceId
- entity
- eventId
- floorId
- floorRefId
- latitude
- longitude
- unit
- ipAddress
- lastSeen
- X
- Y
- Z
- Unit
- locationMapHierarchy
- manufacturer
- antennaIndex
- apMacAddress
- band
- lastHeardInSeconds
- rssi
- slot
- notificationType
- RawX
- RawY
- Unit
- ssid
- subscriptionName
- tagVendorData
- timestamp
- username
```

is there any way to do this in SQL?

Comment: That's JSON. You can't parse JSON by splitting. SQL Server has JSON support since 2016. If you target earlier versions you'll have to parse the JSON data *before* inserting it in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not unstructured data, that's JSON data, a structured format. You can't parse JSON by string splitting. SQL Server 2016 added JSON support, as shown in [Work with JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server)

You can use the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) function to parse the data and extract properties by specifying their path, eg:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'{"notifications":[{"apMacAddress":"20:50:7a:09:5t:30","associated":false,"band":"IEEE_802_11_A","confidenceFactor":192,"deviceId":"34:f4:23:23:f4:wr","entity":"Wired","eventId":2343434,"floorId":3244234234234,"floorRefId":234235465234,"geoCoordinate":{"latitude":-999.0,"longitude":-999.0,"unit":"DEGREES"},"ipAddress":["23.423.23.234"],"lastSeen":"2018-02-09T12:24:53.512+0000","locationCoordinate":{"x":423.2342,"y":23.423,"z":0.0,"unit":"FEET"},"locationMapHierarchy":"North Campus>North SIde>F4>F4 Academies ","manufacturer":"Sony Corporate","maxDetectedRssi":{"antennaIndex":0,"apMacAddress":"234:23:56d:45d:5f:20","band":"IEEE_802_11_B","lastHeardInSeconds":23,"rssi":-54,"slot":2},"notificationType":"locationupdate","rawLocation":{"RawX":0.0,"RawY":0.0,"Unit":null},"ssid":"aide","subscriptionName":" Lab Location","tagVendorData":null,"timestamp":2343657436,"username":"abc.gmail.com"}]}'  

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.notifications')
    with (
        apMacAddress nvarchar(500) '$.apMacAddress',
        associated bit '$.associated',
        band nvarchar(50) '$.band'
    )
```

This will return :

```
apMacAddress        associated  band
20:50:7a:09:5t:30   0           IEEE_802_11_A
```

To parse nested structures, you need to extract the structure with the `AS JSON` clause and apply OPENJSON to it again with CROSS APPLY, eg:

```
SELECT apMacAddress,associated,band,latitude,longitude  
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.notifications')
    with (
        apMacAddress nvarchar(500) '$.apMacAddress',
        associated bit '$.associated',
        band nvarchar(50) '$.band',
        geoCoordinate nvarchar(max) AS JSON
    )
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(geoCoordinate) with (
        latitude decimal(5,2) '$.latitude',
        longitude decimal(5,2) '$.longitude'
    )
```

Will return :

```
apMacAddress        associated  band            latitude    longitude
20:50:7a:09:5t:30   0           IEEE_802_11_A   -999.00     -999.00
```

In earlier versions you have to parse the JSON strings before inserting them into the database, eg using JSON.NET, the most popular JSON parser for .NET.

While there are some JSON parser implementations for earlier versions, like [this one](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) they are complex, slow and hard to use

**UPDATE**

To be clear, OPENJSON is a function like any other table-valued function eg STRING_SPLIT. This means it can be applied to a field using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT *  
from SomeTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(SomeTable.MyJsonField, '$.notifications')
with (
        apMacAddress nvarchar(500) '$.apMacAddress',
        associated bit '$.associated',
        band nvarchar(50) '$.band',
        geoCoordinate nvarchar(max) AS JSON
    )
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(geoCoordinate) 
with (
        latitude decimal(5,2) '$.latitude',
        longitude decimal(5,2) '$.longitude'
)
```

To extract more nested structures, they have to be extracted at the top, then parsed with OPENJSON just like `geoCoordinate`:

```
SELECT apMacAddress,associated,band,latitude,longitude ,x,y
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.notifications')
    with (
        apMacAddress nvarchar(500) '$.apMacAddress',
        associated bit '$.associated',
        band nvarchar(50) '$.band',
        geoCoordinate nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
        locationCoordinate nvarchar(max) AS JSON
    )
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(geoCoordinate) 
    with (
        latitude decimal(5,2) '$.latitude',
        longitude decimal(5,2) '$.longitude'
    )
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(locationCoordinate) with (
        x decimal(5,2) '$.x',
        y decimal(5,2) '$.y'
)
```

Will return the locationCoordinate.x and locationCoordinate.y values :

```
apMacAddress        associated  band            latitude    longitude   x   y
20:50:7a:09:5t:30   0           IEEE_802_11_A   -999.00     -999.00   423.23    23.42
```

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanvos. It is working but how can I get the data from table? Table has many rows in json format

Comment: Just pass the field instead of the variable

Comment: Sorry @Panagiotis Kanvos, I didn't get you.

Comment: Kanvos, I'm still getting some columns as blank. (Example: locationCoordinate - X, Y, Z ,Unit and rawLocation - RawX, RawY, Unit columns)

Comment: @Akhil you'll get blanks if you have typos in the paths, or if you didn't extract the nested structures in the top query.

Comment: @Akhil added another example

Comment: Kanvos, I small help/advice - Is it possible to give any alias names for columns?

Comment: @Akshil you can add an alias to  `OPENJSON` as if it were a table, eg `OPENJSON(...) AS locs` and then use the alias to refer to its columns in the select clause and alias them too, eg `SELECT ...., locs.X as locX, raws.X as rawX`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) reply, suppose you are using SQL Server 2016 and onward (with Compatibility level 130) you can use the `OPENJSON` function.

Another assumption is that you Json structure will **not** change
you can use the following to parse the elements into columns

**UPDATE(!!)**

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##DataSet') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##DataSet

    DECLARE @Table TABLE (Id int identity (1,1) , JsonCol NVARCHAR(MAX))

    INSERT INTO @Table (JsonCol)
    VALUES ('{
      "notifications": [
        {
          "apMacAddress": "20:50:7a:09:5t:30",
          "associated": false,
          "band": "IEEE_802_11_A",
          "confidenceFactor": 192,
          "deviceId": "34:f4:23:23:f4:wr",
          "entity": "Wired",
          "eventId": 2343434,
          "floorId": 3244234234234,
          "floorRefId": 234235465234,
          "geoCoordinate": {
            "latitude": -888.0,
            "longitude": -888.0,
            "unit": "DEGREES"
          },
          "ipAddress": [
            "23.423.23.234"
          ],
          "lastSeen": "2018-02-09T12:24:53.512+0000",
          "locationCoordinate": {
            "x": 423.2342,
            "y": 23.423,
            "z": 0.0,
            "unit": "FEET"
          },
          "locationMapHierarchy": "North Campus>North SIde>F4>F4 Academies ",
          "manufacturer": "Sony Corporate",
          "maxDetectedRssi": {
            "antennaIndex": 0,
            "apMacAddress": "234:23:56d:45d:5f:20",
            "band": "IEEE_802_11_B",
            "lastHeardInSeconds": 23,
            "rssi": -54,
            "slot": 2
          },
          "notificationType": "locationupdate",
          "rawLocation": {
            "RawX": 0.0,
            "RawY": 0.0,
            "Unit": null
          },
          "ssid": "aide",
          "subscriptionName": " Lab Location",
          "tagVendorData": null,
          "timestamp": 2343657436,
          "username": "abc.gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }'),
    ('{
      "notifications": [
        {
          "apMacAddress": "20:50:7a:09:5t:30",
          "associated": false,
          "band": "IEEE_802_11_A",
          "confidenceFactor": 192,
          "deviceId": "34:f4:23:23:f4:wr",
          "entity": "Wired",
          "eventId": 2343434,
          "floorId": 3244234234234,
          "floorRefId": 234235465234,
          "geoCoordinate": {
            "latitude": -999.0,
            "longitude": -999.0,
            "unit": "DEGREES"
          },
          "ipAddress": [
            "23.423.23.234"
          ],
          "lastSeen": "2018-02-09T12:24:53.512+0000",
          "locationCoordinate": {
            "x": 423.2342,
            "y": 23.423,
            "z": 0.0,
            "unit": "FEET"
          },
          "locationMapHierarchy": "North Campus>North SIde>F4>F4 Academies ",
          "manufacturer": "Sony Corporate",
          "maxDetectedRssi": {
            "antennaIndex": 0,
            "apMacAddress": "234:23:56d:45d:5f:20",
            "band": "IEEE_802_11_B",
            "lastHeardInSeconds": 23,
            "rssi": -54,
            "slot": 2
          },
          "notificationType": "locationupdate",
          "rawLocation": {
            "RawX": 0.0,
            "RawY": 0.0,
            "Unit": null
          },
          "ssid": "aide",
          "subscriptionName": " Lab Location",
          "tagVendorData": null,
          "timestamp": 2343657436,
          "username": "abc.gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }')
    ,(
    '{
      "notifications": [
        {
          "apMacAddress": "20:50:7a:09:5t:30",
          "associated": false,
          "band": "IEEE_802_11_A",
          "confidenceFactor": 192,
          "deviceId": "34:f4:23:23:f4:wr",
          "entity": "Wired",
          "eventId": 2343434,
          "floorId": 3244234234234,
          "floorRefId": 234235465234,
          "geoCoordinate": {
            "latitude": -777.0,
            "longitude": -777.0,
            "unit": "DEGREES"
          },
          "ipAddress": [
            "23.423.23.234"
          ],
          "lastSeen": "2018-02-09T12:24:53.512+0000",
          "locationCoordinate": {
            "x": 423.2342,
            "y": 23.423,
            "z": 0.0,
            "unit": "FEET"
          },
          "locationMapHierarchy": "North Campus>North SIde>F4>F4 Academies ",
          "manufacturer": "Sony Corporate",
          "maxDetectedRssi": {
            "antennaIndex": 0,
            "apMacAddress": "234:23:56d:45d:5f:20",
            "band": "IEEE_802_11_B",
            "lastHeardInSeconds": 23,
            "rssi": -54,
            "slot": 2
          },
          "notificationType": "locationupdate",
          "rawLocation": {
            "RawX": 0.0,
            "RawY": 0.0,
            "Unit": null
          },
          "ssid": "aide",
          "subscriptionName": " Lab Location",
          "tagVendorData": null,
          "timestamp": 2343657436,
          "username": "abc.gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }'



    )

    ;WITH  BrkJson as 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Table
    CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON (JsonCol, '$.notifications[0]') R
    )


    ,Dataset as 
    (
    SELECT Id, [key] , [value]
    FROM BrkJson 
    WHERE [type] != 5 /*Array*/ 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.Id ,b.[Key] +'_'+ t.[key] [key] , t.[value]
    FROM BrkJson  b
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (value) t
    WHERE b.[type] = 5 
    )



    SELECT *
    INTO ##DataSet 
    FROM Dataset


    DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @pvt NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols +=','+ QUOTENAME([key])
    FROM ##DataSet
    GROUP BY [key]

    SET @cols = STUFF(@cols,1,1,'')
    --PRINT @cols

    SET @pvt = 
    'SELECT * 
     FROM ##DataSet 
        PIVOT 
            (
            MAX([value]) FOR  [key] in ('+@cols+')
            ) e
    '
    EXEC sp_executesql @Pvt 
    DROP TABLE ##DataSet
```

Comment: Thanks @hkravitz. It is working but how can I get the data from table? Table has many rows in json format

Comment: Isn't OPENJSON what I posted? You don't need to extract keys and values, pivot or concatenate strings, and you definitely *don't* need to execute dynamic SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , I've mentioned you in the comment (In addition to Panagiotis Kanavos...) , if he uses OPENJSON the result set is [Key],[Value],[Type], he needed to transpose it to columns, so instead of writing each of his ~30 elements, it's easier to use dynamic pivot,

Comment: @hkravitz, as per your query, how can I pass a field instead of a variable?

Comment: @Akhil, I've updated the query to pull the json from a table (I've insert the json 3 times with a difference in the longitude and latitude values), please review.